# method onChange not working in radio button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, next.js

I have a form with a radio button that have to do something when the item selected changes, but it only happends when the page loads but no when I select other item

This is my code:

```
           <div key={item} className="lg:w-1/2">
                <label
                  className="flex items-center mx-6"
                  htmlFor={item.option_image.alt}
                >
                  <input
                    className="w-5 h-5 mr-4"
                    type="radio"
                    id={item.option_image.alt}
                    value={item.option_image.alt}
                    name={slice.primary.title}
                    checked={item.option_image.alt === category}
                    onChange={console.log(item.option_image.alt)}
                    required
                  />
                  <Image
                    src={item.option_image.url}
                    width={item.option_image.dimensions.width}
                    height={item.option_image.dimensions.height}
                    alt={item.option_image.alt}
                  />
                  <p className="flex-1 my-auto ml-2 text-lg text-white 2xl:mr-4">
                    {item.option_label}
                  </p>
                </label>
              </div>
```

Comment: You have to pass functions to your `onChange` prop. Right now, you're just immediately logging. One example of passing a function: `onChange={() => console.log(item.option_image.alt)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create an arrow function as such:

```
onChange={()=>console.log(item.option_image.alt)}
```

What you are doing now is simply accessing the onChange method.

Notice the difference:

With `onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}`, you are essentially creating a new function that calls onChange method during each render.

With `onChange={onChange}`, you are directly accessing onChange method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it like this:

```
                onChange={() => console.log(item.option_image.alt)}
```

If you don't do it like this, it will run the console on the first load of the page, not when the radio is clicked.